# How can I share a drive between windows 7 and mac osx, so both have read/write access?

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive

I have a Macbook Pro with an OptiBay kit, and a 500GB SATA drive in the OptiBay. I have my primary HD setup with Bootcamp running Windows 7.

I want to set up my Optibay drive so that both Windows and OSX have read/write access to it. I formatted drive at NTFS and Windows works with it great. It is mounted as my D: drive. However, when I boot into OSX, the drive says it's Read Only.

What can I do to get this drive set up so that Windows and OSX can both have read/write access?

Note: i will never have both my bootcamp and osx running at the same time (I'm not running bootcamp in VMWare Fusion or any other VM), so there will never be a chance for them to clobber each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the [ntfs-3g driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/) for OS X. It will allow you to write to the volume.